# How can I create a single/multiple selection dialog using JQueryUI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

JQueryUI has a very nice [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), but I wonder how I could create a similar dialog with multiple values I can select from.

It does not necessarily need to have a text area. Similar to how the right-click window looks or how the selection dialogs work on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do here, but I think you mean that you have various different options from which you want you want your user to select one.  You can do this by creating multiple buttons using the `buttons` option:

```
$(selector).dialog({
    buttons: {
        'button 1': function() {
            // handle if button 1 is clicked
        },
        'button 2': function() {
            // handle if button 2 is clicked
        },
        'button 3': function() {
            // handle if button 3 is clicked
        }
    }
});
```

If this isn't what you need, perhaps you could provide a more detailed explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Not exactly as I wanted but very nice. If you happen to know how to tell the buttons to be one under the other, that would be even more awesome.